# How do I disable new lines for functions within functions and string literals?

Tags: javascript, eslint

So I'm using Prettier and ESLint in VSCode and each time I format my code I am getting a annoying new lines inside my if statements and string literals.
Both of these I'd like to disable to see how to write them to avoid the multi-line mess it ends up with.

I have tried all the ESLint rules I can find that seem to be related:

```
"rules": {
            "no-console": "off",
            "no-debugger": "off",
            "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "args": "none" }],
            "eslint brace-style": [ "error", "1tbs", {"allowSingleLine": true}],
            "object-property-newline": ["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": true}],
            "array-bracket-newline": ["error", "never"],
            "array-element-newline": ["error", "never"],
            "function-paren-newline": ["error", "never"],
            "object-curly-newline": ["error", "never"]
        },
```

But formatting always produces this:

```
if (
    confirm(
        `Are you sure you want to delete the task "${
            this.tasks[tid].name
        }"?`
    )
)
    this.$delete(this.tasks, tid)
```

Instead of:

```
if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the task "${this.tasks[tid].name}"?`))
    this.$delete(this.tasks, tid)
```

Or at least:

```
if (
    confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete the task "${this.tasks[tid].name}"?`)
    )
    this.$delete(this.tasks, tid)
```

Anyone have an idea how to change that?

And before someone states the obvious, I understand that it may look better in some ways here, but it is so spaced out it makes simple functions really long. Especially the string literal separation.

Comment: What is the warning you get ?

Comment: `"max-len": ["error", { "ignoreComments": true, "ignoreUrls": true, "ignoreStrings": true, "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true, "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true }]`
Was added with no effect.